# Invisible height in Flash's CheckBox when used in a ScrollPane for auto-calculation of height

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, checkbox, scrollpane

When using `fl.controls.CheckBox` inside a `fl.controls.ScrollPane`, it seems that whenever the last item in ScrollPane's children container is a `CheckBox`, `ScrollPane`'s `update()` method always leaves significant blank space below the CheckBox, although I specifically set the size of the CheckBox.

**Question**: How do I remove the invisible height from the CheckBox?

Answer (score 1):

I've researched in many places and finally found a useful post by this awesome person in the link below. All credits goes to him, Infineon. I can't trace to the flash support forum he is referring to though.

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showpost.php3?p=842806&postcount=6

The solution to the above invisible height problem is really hard to find as a dig of the Flash AS3 documentation doesn't turn up `override protected function configUI():void` method easily. At least I haven't found it till now, and I will never have known about it either without some kind of prior knowledge into the inner workings.

**Note*:* This solution doesn't only work on `CheckBox`. Other form UI widgets like `fl.controls.RadioButton` also works the same way.

As noted below, this is because of the package hard-coding width and height of the rectangle in the super class of the widget. We will need to override it so that the invisible rectangle becomes smaller or editable.

I will reproduce his code verbatim here to prevent link rot:

```as3
package com.your.package.here
{
    import fl.controls.CheckBox;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

    public class WidgetCheckBox extends CheckBox
    {

        public function WidgetCheckBox()
        {
        }

        override protected function configUI():void 
        {
            super.configUI();

            // remove the background movie clip added in the superclass
            removeChild(background);

            // redraw the hit area of the checkbox component
            var bg:Shape = new Shape();
            var g:Graphics = bg.graphics;
            g.beginFill(0, 0);

            // draw the background area using the width and the height of the 
            // component, instead of hardcoding these properties ( in the
            // superclass the width and height of the rectangle were 100 and 100
            g.drawRect(0, 0, _width, _height);

            g.endFill();
            background = bg as DisplayObject;

            // add the new background
            addChildAt(background, 0);
        }

        override public function set label(value:String):void 
        {
            super.label = value;

            // in the superclass the size of the label textfield was set to
            // 100 by 100 px; instead of using these values, autosize the
            // textfield every time a new label is set
            textField.multiline = false;
            textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        }
    }

}
```

Then all you need to do is to import the new class you have extended:

```as3
var checkBox:WidgetCheckBox = new WidgetCheckBox();
```

Hope this helps some people to relieve their head-scratching.